# Uncaught Exception in PhpSpreadsheet: File does not exist

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpspreadsheet

```text
Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception: 
File "C:\xampp\tmp\php93C3.tmp" does not exist. 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbjalansumbawa\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File.php:147 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dbjalansumbawa\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory.php(133): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File::assertFile('C:\\xampp\\tmp\\ph...')  
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dbjalansumbawa\function.php(158): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReaderForFile('C:\\xampp\\tmp\\ph...')  
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dbjalansumbawa\tabel.php(2): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')  
#3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbjalansumbawa\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File.php on line 147
```

Anyone can help me about this problem?

Why doesn't the file exist?

Comment: Please add the code that causes this problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).